# Firebase Access a children if I don't know two childs who have unknown ids

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

How can I access the data of the children memberId or name and photoURL of the child "members"?
You can see the structure of my database in images.
[image]

[image]

I tried to use queryOrdered and queryEqual but I just can use it one time

I tried like that because I know the room.key who is the "key" on the database.

```
let refParticipants = refDatabase.child("markers").queryOrdered(byChild: "key").queryEqual(toValue: room.key)
    refParticipants.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
...
}
```

I use Swift 3.1

I update my answer with that screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I try it but when I open the message there's that message: {
  "error" : "Auth token is expired"
}

Comment: So are seeking to check what rooms a specific user is a member of?

Comment: I want to show in a tableView all members who are in the room except the user who created this room, it's the same who created the marker and put it on the map

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to access the child nodes of

```
/markers/oHQ.../members/9oBKY...
```

Let's simply the structure for this answer

```
markers
  marker_0
   members
     member_0
       name: "J"
     member)1
       name: "K"
```

and then the code that will access each member within the members node and print their name

```
let markersRef = self.ref.child("markers")
let marker0Ref = markersRef.child("marker_0")
let membersRef = marker0Ref.child("members")
membersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let name = dict["name"] as! String
        print(name)
    }
})
```

and the output will be

```
J
K
```

Since you know the parent node (oHQa...), which contains the child node 'members', it doesn't really matter as to what each members key is since you are iterating over them.

However, if you are wanting to query for certain members or other member data, you may want to consider flattening the database a bit like this

```
markers
  oHQa...
    //marker data
marker_members
  member_0
     name: "J"
     member_of: "oHQa..."
  member_1
     name: "K"
     member_of: "oHQa..."
```

With this structure you can query for all the members of any marker or query for all members whose name is "J" etc.

As a side note, in the structure in the question you have the member_id as both the key as well as a child which is unnecessary. If it's the key then you can always directly access that node without a query.

Comment: Ok I will try that but how can I increments the number of member, first is member_0 then if I want the second is member_1, how to do that? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @GhiggzPikkoro The for loop *for child in snapshot.children* does that for you. It will iterate over all of the children in the members snapshot i.e. it will process each child in members one at a time and print the name.

Comment: Ok I did it thank you Jay but one last question, how can I delete the member_1 when he quit the room if I don't know which member_number he is? Because if there's a lot of members I can't know which one is the member_1 or member_2 etc.

Comment: @GhiggzPikkoro Your app will know! A common practice is to iterate over each node and store the data for each member within an array of classes. A class would contain say the member name, maybe a thumbnail and most importantly the *key* to their node. In my example the keys would be member_0, member_1. If the keys were created with childByAutoId then it will be whatever those id's were. Big picture is that id doesn't matter - when a member quits a room, their key will be stored in an array, so you get that key and memberRef.delete(key) to remove it from the actual Firebase node.

Comment: Ok maybe you could show me a piece of code that how you could do that?